# OWIN Authentication and Custom Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I create a **custom** **BasicAuthenticationMiddleware** that use a **BasicAuthenticationHandler** to Authenticate requests from client to WebAPI.

The **BasicAuthenticationHandler** derives from the **AuthenticationHandler< TOptions >** base class.

Everything works fine and I implemented the

**AuthenticateCoreAsync** 
where the logic to authenticate happens

**ApplyChallengeResponseAsync** 
where the logic, in case of not authenticated requests, sends the WWW-Authenticate header to the client.

What I would like to achieve now is to set a Custom Body in the Response (IOwinResponse, inside the ApplyChallengeResponseAsync, with a custom object like:

```
{
Code="999",
Description="My failing reason"
AdditionalInfo = "My additional infos"
}
```

instead of the standard message that is like

```
{
    message="Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Did you have any suggestion on this?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard message you see, which is "Authorization has been denied for this request." is created by the `Authorize` filter. The `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method sets this message in the response.

```
protected virtual void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
    }

    actionContext.Response = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request
                                 .CreateErrorResponse(
                                    HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
                                      SRResources.RequestNotAuthorized);
}
```

`SRResources.RequestNotAuthorized` is what you see as the standard message.

Now, `ApplyChallengeResponseAsync` is called from the `OnSendingHeaders` callback in Katana autentication micro framework. This callback is invoked when a component writes into the response stream. In our case, when the response message created by the filter (what you see above) gets serialized, that is when the callback is invoked and `ApplyChallengeResponseAsync` runs. By that time, it is already too late for you to change the response. The best bet will be to override the virtual method of the `Authorize` filter above like this.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<MyError>
                                (new MyError() { Description = "My failing reason" });
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

        actionContext.Response = response;
    }
}

public class MyError
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of using `[Authorize]` on the controller or action method, use `[MyAuthorize]`.

Comment: Thank you! It was simple but I missed it.