# Returning Descriptive 401 Messages From Owin WebApi2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, authorize-attribute

I have an asp.net 4.5 web api running using owin. Whenever an unauthorized request is made it returns a 401 with the following response as expected:

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

I would like to add additional detail to this response (expired token, invalid role, etc...) and implemented a custom `[AuthorizeAttribute]` based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26124190/585552).

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<MyError>
            (new MyError() { Description = "This is why you're unauthorized" });
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        actionContext.Response = response;
    }
}
```

and then used it on my controllers like this:

```
[MyAuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "Foo")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

which returns a 401 with the following response as expected:

```
{"Description": "This is why you're unauthorized"}
```

However, I do not see how to determine the reason the request is unauthorized from the `HttpActionContext` passed to `MyAuthorizeAttribute.HandleUnauthorizedRequest`. For instance, when I'm debugging locally and make a request with an expired token it throws a `SecurityTokenExpiredException` explaining `IDX10223: Lifetime validation failed. The token is expired. ValidTo: '...' Current time: '...'.` or with a invalid audience it throws a `SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException` explaining `Message=IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '...'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '...'.` I've set several breakpoints in my `Startup.cs` yet have been unable to even catch one of these exceptions before they're thrown.

**How can I determine the specific reason a request is unauthorized using owin middleware?**

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out how to identify expirations nor invalid audiences and such, but I ended up using this to at least return `403`s based on roles.

*You can customize the message ("You must have role X to access this action ...") using the example in my question above.*

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal != null && 
            actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
            Roles != null)
        {
            if (!Roles.Split(',').Any(x => 
                actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(x.Trim())))
            {
                actionContext.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @Greg any chance yet to handle this using OWIN ?